# Hibernate generate POJOs with Equals

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, reverse-engineering, pojo

We are using hibernate in a new project where we use the `hibernate.reveng.xml` to create our `*.hbm.xml` files and POJOs after that. We want to have equals methods in each of our POJOs. 
I found that you can use `<meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>` in your hbm files to mark which properties to use in the equals. But this would mean editing alot of files, and then re-editing the files again in the future if/when we modify tables or columns in our DB.

**So I was wondering if there is a way to place which properties to use in the equals method for each pojo(table) in the `hibernate.reveng.xml` file?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an undocumented feature (and the online [DTD](http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd) is out of date) but you can add `<meta>` in the `<table>` and `<colum>` elements. In other words, you should be able to do this:

```
<table name="PROPERTY" catalog="DATA" schema="PUBLIC">
  <meta attribute="extends">BasicDataObject</meta>
  <meta attribute="scope-class">public abstract</meta>
  <column name="ID">
    <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
    <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
  </column>
</table>
```

The DTD in **hibernate-tools.jar** should be up-to-date (and looks like [this one](http://seaminaction.googlecode.com/svn/demos/articles/edas2-perflab/resources/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd)) and declare:

```
<!ELEMENT column (meta*) >
```

There is [a discussion](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=85839) about this in the Seam in Action forums.

Answer (score 2):

eclipse has equal and hash code generator. We use that for generation of those methods.

Comment: @dr jerry When you db schema changes, do you regenerate your pojos and then manually go back through them and readd the equals add hash code?

Comment: No after db changes, i do not regenerate. At some point we left the generation thing and do a manual update of our pojo's. Our configuration is too much tweaked to benefit from code generation.