# hibernate tools toString and equals method generation

Tags: hibernate, code-generation, reverse-engineering, hibernate-tools

Below is my hibernate mapping file i want to generate toString and equals method using 
hibernate tool ant task.

```
<class name="org.hibernate.db.Country" table="country" catalog="world">
    <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
    <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
    <id name="code" type="string">
        <column name="Code" length="3" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>      
</class>
```

but i am not able to generate toString or equals method is there any thing wrong in this mapping file.

i have checked hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd  and hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd files both are up to date.

Best Regards,
Vivek S. Shah

Comment: hmm, one year ago someone had the same problem - without answer :/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945160/how-to-get-hibernate-tools-to-generate-pojos-with-tostring-equals-and-hashcode

Comment: Maybe this thread helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523826/hibernate-generate-pojos-with-equals

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you missed name="country" property at class level.

I have verified in **hibernate 4**,by adding meta data in the hiernate mapping file,equals and hashcode methods are creating as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="com.hrdb.Employee" name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" schema="PUBLIC">
        <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
        <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
        <id name="eid" type="integer">
            <column name="EID" length="255" not-null="true" precision="19"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstname" type="string">
            <column name="FIRSTNAME" length="255" not-null="false" precision="19"/>
        </property>
```

You can also define these meta data at property level.

```
<property name="name" type="string">
      <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
      <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>      
</property>
```